# Etimologia di vago

Tags: etymology

Mi ha sempre incuriosito il senso letterario di *vago* col significato di:

> Leggiadro, bello, grazioso, o amabile, piacevole (con questi significato è di solito anteposto al sostantivo). Riferito a persona o ai suoi atti:
>
> - *O vaghe montanine pasturelle, Donde venite sì legiadre e belle?
>   (Sacchetti); Tre vaghissime donne a cui le trecce Infiora di felici
>   itale rose Giovinezza (Foscolo)*.

Non riesco a trovarne l’etimologia. [Treccani.it](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vago1/) cita il latino “vagus” col significato di indeterminato, ma da dove  deriva  il senso di bello/piacevole?

> vago¹ [dal lat. vagus "vagante, instabile; indeterminato"]

Comment: Che possa derivare dall'arabo? (trovato qui come cenno http://www.etimo.it/?term=vago)

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi Onestamente è meglio ignorare qualsiasi cosa sia su etimo.it - le etimologie di Pianigiani sono fantasiose e di solito non supportate da niente più che una vaga impressione.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Penso che questo [articolo dell'Enciclopedia Dantesca](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/vago_%28Enciclopedia-Dantesca%29/) renda abbastanza bene l'idea.

Come hai trovato sul vocabolario Treccani, "vago" proviene dal latino *vagus*, che significa  "vagante, instabile; indeterminato".

Come spiega l'articolo sopra citato, da questo significato deriva l'uso dell'aggettivo che comincia a farsi nel lessico medievale proprio del corteggiamento amoroso, in cui il senso di "vagante" farebbe riferimento al movimiento degli occhi, agli sguardi del corteggiatore sulla persona amata:

> La Castellano ha ben chiarito come la diffusione di v. nell'italiano due-trecentesco tragga origine dal vocabolario del corteggiamento amoroso, spesso affidato, nel costume medievale, al muto linguaggio degli occhi e degli sguardi: una riprova indiretta della validità di questa tesi si ha anzi nel fatto che D., su 20 presenze complessive, usi v. nove volte in stretta correlazione con ‛ occhi ', o altri sostantivi di ugual significato, o con il verbo ‛ vedere '.

A un certo punto, comincia a usarsi l'aggettivo "vago" per descrivere le qualità delle donne capaci di suscitare questi "sguardi vaganti", come in questi versi Duecenteschi di [Patecchio](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI21/00000634.jpg):

> No se meta en vertue om de femena
> vaga: / çamai no n’issirà levement, o’ q’el vada.

Da qui deriverebbe il significato di "vago" come sinonimo di "bello, piacevole a vedersi, leggiadro, grazioso".